# Drill down charts dynamic functionality

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am getting null value for canvas element in the typescript code. There is a static pie chart, after clicking on it , drill-down to its child pie charts.

In the onclick functionality, I am hiding the parent and showing child using *ngIf. child charts are not displaying.

Html code:

```
<div>
        <canvas *ngFor="let chart of charts; let i = index" id="canvas{{i}}" #mycanvas></canvas>
    </div>
```

Type script code:

```
@ViewChildren("mycanvas") divView: ElementRef;
  array = [];
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.createCharts(this.array);
  }
  charts = [];
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createChartsData();
  }

  createChartsData() {


    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var pie = {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels: ["Disks", "Mgmt", "Hardware", "FC", "Vols&Pols"],
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: ["#008000", "#008000", "#008000", "#008000", "#008000"],
                    data: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: { display: false },
                animations: true,
                tooltips: { enabled: true },
                legend: { display: true }
            }
        };
        this.array.push(pie);
    }


}
 createCharts(pieData) {
console.log(this.elementRef);
console.log(this.divView+" 777777777dfd");
var ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.divView.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        /* let htmlRef = this.divView.nativeElement.select(`canvas` + j);
        console.log(htmlRef);
        var tempChart = new Chart(htmlRef, pieData[j]);
        this.charts.push(tempChart); */
    }
}
```

this.divView, is coming as null. Could you let me know what is the issue with above code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue on the same day posted. Sorry for replying late.
Issue was I am using charts array for canvas to iterate and create canvas. Canvas array is using canvas template variable, kind of a deadlock. So always I am getting element reference for canvas undefined. Got fixed. Let me know if any one need the other code, I can post it.

Comment: iam also looking for same behavior but with static data. can you post me the working code